# Qt's QTextEdit has big memory leak problem

Tags: qt, memory-leaks, qtextedit

In my object, I display the log file in a QTextEdit widget. Then I find the program consumption hundres MB of memory even the log file size is small . And the memory is not released when its content is cleared.

Then I write a small demo in the QtCreator with Qt5.12.x , just put a QTextEdit widget on it.
call the append function to inject QString in it , the problem recurr, even I delete the QTextEdit widget.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
{

    QPushButton *btn1  = new QPushButton(this) ;
    QPushButton *btn2  = new QPushButton(this) ;

    txtEdit = new QTextEdit(this) ;


    QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout ;
    layout->addWidget( btn1 ) ;
    layout->addWidget( btn2 ) ;
    layout->addWidget(txtEdit ) ;

    QWidget *widget = new QWidget;
    widget->setLayout(layout);

    setCentralWidget(widget);

    connect( btn1 , SIGNAL( clicked(  ) ) , this , SLOT( setdata( ) ) ) ;
    connect( btn2 , SIGNAL( clicked(  ) ) , this , SLOT( cleardata( ) ) ) ;

}


void MainWindow::setdata(    )
{

    for ( int ii = 0 ; ii < 50 ; ii++ )
    {


        for ( int i = 0 ; i < 500 ; i++ )
        {

           QString str ;

           for ( int j = 0 ; j < 100 ; j++ )
           {

               str = str+ QString::number( j ) ;
           }

            txtEdit->append( str ) ;

        }

    }

}


void MainWindow::cleardata(  )
{

    txtEdit->clear() ;

    //txtEdit->close( ) ;

    //delete  txtEdit ;

}
```

Comment: How are you measuring this memory usage?

Comment: you can see it in the task manager so something like.

Answer (score 2):

That's intentional.
QTextEdit is a HTML viewer, with word wrap, undo buffer and all the benefits.

It's not a `QPlainTextEdit` if that's what you're looking for.

Try: `txtEdit->setUndoRedoEnabled(false);`, that should at least fix your 'memory leak'.
Performance improvements can be made by disabling word wrap.

Comment: Thanks , but sorry , I don't understand what do you mean ? I just want to show a lot qstrings in the QTextEdit . And ,I have tried the QPlainTextEdit , it also has this problem.

Comment: @cyberpunker optimal performance you get without word wrap. memory usage won't improve though. Scintilla uses similar amount for your test data.

Comment: I call  setUndoRedoEnabled(false) just after construction , then it still can not return the memory  when called  clear() .  I do this on a debian, and I see its status in the task manager.

Comment: @cyberpunker I always use `QPlainTextEdit` for displaying "infinite" logs, and never have memory leaks when using [setMaximumBlockCount](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html#maximumBlockCount-prop). May be `setMaximumBlockCount()` is what you're looking for

Comment: Yes , this limit the display rows . But if you set setMaximumBlockCount to 3M lines , how much memory will it take ?  And  if  you just want to load a  30MB log file into it and  clear the content ,  the hundres MB memory is still ocupied ,  do you think it acceptale ?

Comment: @Jeroen3  no help.